# Sum data from data frame 1 according to matching conditions in data frame 2 within an interval

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have two data frames. The first one holds observations for a specific ID in a time interval with given StartDate and EndDate. The second data frame holds observations for the same specific IDs but on a specific date.

```
ID <- c(86041, 87371, 98765, 90010)
DateStart <- as.Date((c("2022-02-04", "2022-02-04", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08")))
DateEnd <- as.Date((c("2022-02-07", "2022-02-10","2022-02-11", "2022-02-11")))
Interaction <- c(122, 73, 105, 82)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, DateStart, DateEnd, Interaction)

ID <- c(86041, 86041, 87371, 87371, 98765, 98765, 90010, 90010)
date <- as.Date(c("2022-02-04", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-06", "2022-02-09", "2022-02-09", "2022-02-11", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-10"))
view <- c(25, 67, 21, 36, 43, 61, 14, 34)
read <- c(13, 37, 29, 15, 37, 51, 9, 25)
df2 <- data.frame(ID, date, view, read)
```

I want to sum all the events from the second data frame for a specific ID within the interval between StartDate and Enddate and add this as another column in the first data frame.

So I tried writing a function to get the aggregate of "view" for a certain ID in a specific time interval and applying it to df1, but I only get 0 as return and it does not look very elegant:

```
calc_view <- function(ID, StartDate, EndDate) {
  sum(df2$view[which(df2$ID == ID & 
                       df2$date >= StartDate & 
                       df2$date <= EndDate)])
}

df1$view <- apply(df1, 1, calc_view, StartDate = df1$StartDate, EndDate = df1$EndDate)
```

The desired output should present the count of aggregated events for "view" and "read" for a specific ID in the interval between StartDate and EndDate given in df1. So something like this:

```
     ID  DateStart    DateEnd Interaction view read
1 86041 2022-02-04 2022-02-07         122   92   50
2 87371 2022-02-04 2022-02-10          73   57   44
3 98765 2022-02-08 2022-02-11         105  104   88
4 90010 2022-02-08 2022-02-11          82   48   34
```

I'm quite new to r and suppose there's a better option, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What exactly do you mean by "sum all the events from the second data frame"? It might help to see the output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I added the desired output in the initial question. I hope this clarifies what I am trying to do.